# Can you explain the weird behaviour of this Java Regex situation?

Tags: java, regex

I've been using the below code to try and extract the different sections out of the text I provided.

It should pick out the digits, and then any sections enclosed in `[` braces or `"` quotation marks into the groups. Here is the code.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Launcher2 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintRegexes("100.000[$₮-45]");
    }
    public static void PrintRegexes(String textToMatch){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[.*?\\]|\".*?\")?.*?(\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*?(?:\\.\\d+)?).*?(\\[.*?\\]|\".*?\")",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(textToMatch);
        if (m.find())
        {
            for(int groups =0;groups<m.groupCount();groups++){
                System.out.println("Group "+groups+" contains "+m.group(groups));
            }
            for(int groups =0;m.find(groups);groups++){ //this will error, but right now, it's the least of my concerns
                System.out.println("Group "+groups+" contains "+m.group(groups));
            }
        }

    }
}

Group 0 contains 100.000[$₮-45]
Group 1 contains null
Group 2 contains 100.000
Group 3 contains [$₮-45]
Group 0 contains 100.000[$₮-45]
Group 1 contains null
Group 2 contains 0.000
Group 3 contains [$₮-45]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 4 //don't care about this, I've got bigger strings(fish) to regex(fry) at the moment!
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
    at Launcher2.PrintRegexes(Launcher2.java:21)
    at Launcher2.main(Launcher2.java:10)
```

All the groups are the same except for `group 2`, one prints out as `0.000`, one prints out as `100.000`.

**Why is this?**

This behaviour goes away if I but something infront AND behind the digits.

If I just put something in front, I get this output:

```
Group 0 contains [$₮-45]100.000
Group 1 contains [$₮-45]
Group 2 contains 100.000
Group 3 contains null
Group 0 contains [$₮-45]100.000
Group 1 contains null
Group 2 contains 45
Group 3 contains null
```

Even Weirder! The strangest part (for me) is that this works on www.debuggex.com.

Am I writing my pattern wrong? Or is it that matcher doesn't work out the groups on when this method `Matcher m = p.matcher(textToMatch);` constructs it, and that effects it's behaviour?

Comment: That is one over-complicated regex. What are you trying to do here? What different kinds of input are you expecting?

Comment: @Keppil It was split into smaller sections, for readability, but due to poor version control, I scrapped it. It's this group `(\[.*?\]|".*?")` to grab anything in braces or quotes. And then digits. And then the previous group.

Comment: @Gigatron I don't see what else it could do that what I said. It should collect 0-1 `sections enclosed in [ braces or " quotation marks"`, then there can by anything in between that and digits (with thousands separators, and decimal places), and then there can be anything, and then 0-1 `sections enclosed in [ braces or " quotation marks"`. Possible inputs are `[$₮-45]100.000`, `100.000[$₮-45]`, `"$₮-45"100,000.00`, `"$₮-45"10`.

Comment: `\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d{3}` for the number part

Comment: @BenHanson what if we get `10` as an input? It matches the first term, `\d{1,3}` then looks for zero or more of `(,\d{3})`, and *then* a period with exactly three trailing digits. It doesn't match.

Comment: @Pureferret just make that bit optional then: `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{3})?`. Is that what you mean? Also, my complete answer is: `(\[.*?\]|".*?")?.*?(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{3})?).*?(\[.*?\]|".*?")?`. If I'm missing something, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two problems here.

Firstly, you call `m.find()` multiple times with the group as argument, which doesn't work the way you think it does.
If you look at the [JavaDoc for find(int start)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28int%29), you see that it resets the matcher, and then restarts the search starting at the specified character of the input. This explains the shorter number sequences matched in later iterations.

Secondly, you need to loop until `groups <= m.groupCount()` to get all groups:

```
    Pattern p =
            Pattern.compile("(\\[.*?\\]|\".*?\")?.*?(\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*?(?:\\.\\d+)?).*?(\\[.*?\\]|\".*?\")",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(textToMatch);
    if (m.find()) {
        for (int groups = 0; groups <= m.groupCount(); groups++) {
            System.out.println("Group " + groups + " contains " + m.group(groups));
        }
    }
```

prints

> Group 0 contains 100.000[$₮-45]
>   Group 1 contains null
>   Group 2 contains 100.000
>   Group 3 contains [$₮-45]

Comment: I call `m.find(int)` multiple times, it just returns an a boolean if it finds that group, right? Why wouldn't that be a valid use? Also your point about `<=` and not just `<` is completely valid.

Comment: @Pureferret: Clarified what is going on with the find() calls.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with this part: `(?:,\\d{3})*?`

I think you need `((?:,\\d{3})*)?`

Comment: Actually, just remove the `?`

Comment: True, the `?` is redundant because the `*` allows none, once, or more.

Comment: @Keppil See Gigatron's reply. You think you understand non-greedy quantifiers, but you don't. Don't feel bad, most people don't. Not every regex problem is solved by adding `?` to `*`, although most people think this is the case. If you play with http://www.benhanson.net/cpp/regextl/regextl.zip things should become clearer. BTW my favourite regex fail is when someone puts `.*?` at the *end* of a regex and then wonders why it doesn't match! The reason is of course that in this case a minimal match is nothing, which is therefore preferred...